# Choice for class design

Tags: c++, class

I have the typical problem of class design and I would like to have your opinion.

Let's imagine that I have a base class Animal. From this class I derive several classes of specific animals. I am interested in their mutual interactions. Since their interaction can vary from one animal to another, what I did is to create the base class with pure virtual functions, ie, an abstract class:

> class dog;
>
> class cat;
>
> class bird;
>
> class Animal{
>
> private:
>
> int legs;
>
> public:
>
> virtual void Interact(const dog &) = 0;
>
> virtual void Interact(const cat &) = 0;
>
> virtual void Interact(const bird &) = 0;
>
> };

Then, for each specific animal I create a derived class from the Animal class. For instance:

> class dog: public Animal{
>
> // Implementation of interaction with other animals:
>
> void Interact(const dog & object) {...body...};
>
> void Interact(const cat & object) {...body...};
>
> void Interact(const bird & object) {...body...};
>
> };

Similarely for cat and bird classes.
Now I am concerned with bird class. Birds can fly and have extra variables/methods that dog and cat don't have. What would be a smart way to manage that ? For instance, a brute force way would be to add to the Base class Animal extra methods and variables like `int wings` and `void fly()`. The point is that they would not be used by dog and cat classes. It is not clean.
Maybe another way woul be to declare a derived class FlyingAnimal from Animal:

> class FlyingAnimal: public Animal{
>
> private:
>
> int wings;
>
> public:
>
> void Fly();
>
> };

and then I could create class Bird from this one instead of Animal:

> class Bird: public FlyingAnimal{
>
> body and definition of void Interact(...)...
>
> };

What do you think about that ? Maybe you have another suggestion.

Many thanks in advance !
Xtof

Comment: What excatly is your `interact` method supposed to do and in what way does the behavior differ between what the animal is interacting with?

Answer (score 2):

Having a different interact-method for each possible other animal will work when you have only three classes, but when you add mice, rabbits, tigers, rats, enchiladas, wombats, dolphins, armadillos and zebras, it will quickly get unwieldy, because whenever you add a new animal you need to edit every existing class to add a new interact-method. This is not how object-oriented programming should be. The purpose of OOP is that you can simply add a new class and all other classes can work with it immediately without requiring any modification.

For that reason you should handle the interactions in a more generalized way. Why does a cat hunt a mouse or a bird, but not a dog? What would happen when I would confront a cat with a smibblat? (A smibblat is a small, fluffy, four-legged, herbivorous mammal about 5 centimeters long which I just made up and wrote a `class Smibblat: public Animal` for). Even when the cat has never seen a Smibblat before, it would try to hunt it, because it fits into its prey-pattern. Cats are a danger to all animals which are 1. smaller and 2. slower than themself.

When you would add an abstract `getSize()` and an abstract `getSpeed()` method to class Animal, you could have a method like this:

```
void Cat::interact(const Animal & other) {
     if (other.getSpeed() < this.getSpeed() &&
         other.getSize() < this.getSize()) {
         this.eat(other);
     }
}
```

which can be applied to any new animal you create. The Cat class would no longer have a dependency on every other Animal sub-class there is. It only depends on Animal which provides all the methods which matter for making the decision whether or not to eat the other Animal.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The way I did it, I'll have to edit every class each time I create a new derived class. In addition, I'll have to edit the Base class, which is not good for maintenance or if I want to release the code. The user would have to edit the Base class, which is not userfriendly...However, the solution you propose is not what I'm looking for. I would like to avoid the 'if' in the classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think first thing which you do wrong is having derived classes in the interface of the base class.
You should use [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You can create universal Interaction visitor or three separate visitors for all of your three animal classes. And then you provide the animal you want to interact with as constructor parameter.

Comment: Yes, having the derived classes in the interface of the base class if maybe not the best. I did not know the Visitor pattern. I looked for some examples by googling. It's not trivial to understand...but I think I get the idea...more or less ! I guess I need some good example. Do you have some ?What I understand is that it allows the double dispatch, ie the action to do depends on both objects, not only on the argument. Correct ?